# Which one is more likely to be random walk?

Tags: time-series, random-walk

Consider the two series in the chart below: $walkA$ and $walkB$.

They are based on the same steps, although the steps come in a different order.

Indeed, $stepsA$ and $stepsB$ have identical sample mean $\hat \mu=0.5$ and sample std dev $\hat \sigma=3$.

However, from a visual inspection, I would intuitively say that $walkA$ is more likely to be a random walk than $walkB$.

Is it there a mathematical method to make such claims?

[image]

Comment: Both are equally likely  (Proof: by definition, the increments of a random walk are independent, whence they are exchangeable, and these walks have the same increments up to a permutation.) What you need to do, somehow, is capture the *pyschology* of human pattern identification in order to characterize which sample paths might get your attention as being "unusual."  Usually, for our observations to be objectively meaningful, we specify those events beforehand and make them relevant to whatever it is we are studying.

Comment: Do you have some context, or is it just some exercise? If you look at the steps, that is basicalla an uo-or-down, that is, binary process. If you have some reason to doubt the independence of these steps, then the null of independence can be tested with a runs test, maybe. Search this site ... but your sample size is to small to get much, I guess.

Comment: RE: *"the increments of a random walk are independent"* — could testing the serial correlation of the steps tell anything? In this example, $stepsA$ have serial correlation $0.56$ while $stepsB$ have serial correlation $1.00$. I appreciate that any permutation could occur, but it is very unlikely that a permutation with serial correlation $1.0$ occurs. If you individually check all the $10!$ permutations there are few permutations like that. By contrast, there are many more permutations with serial correlation $0.0$

Comment: Sure, testing serial correlation works.  But in the context of your question this is a fundamental fallacy, because only after observing the blue walk would you conceive of this test: it's an *ex post facto* hypothesis.  If, on the other hand, *before* observing the data you were to adopt a null hypothesis like "increments are independent" and an alternative hypothesis "the lag-1 correlation of the increments is nonzero," *then* the serial correlation test would be justified.

Comment: I'm not sure it's an ex post facto hypothesis--we ex ante know that a random walk is constructed by integrating/summing up independent random samples. This implies that the derivative of a random walk (the steps) should have an autocorrelation of 0 for any lag. Or am I missing something?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A random walk has the property that its derivative should be pure uncorrelated noise. In other words, the autocorrelation of the steps for any lag should be 0.

We can permute the order of your steps a couple of times to obtain a distribution of autocorrelations for lag 1:

[image]

The lag 1 autocorrelation of your steps A is -0.5606 and for your steps B 0.7000.

I presume the high negative autocorrelation for steps A is because you deliberately tried to make your example appear as 'random' as possible and it therefore zig-zags around more than a truly random walk would? That is, you seem to have constructed something more akin to violet noise?

In any case, this distribution allows us to calculate the probability of finding a lag 1 autocorrelation as extreme as yours. One way to do this is to perhaps take the absolute value of the autocorrelations (as we had no clear hypothesis about the sign) and then to count how many simulated samples are as extreme as the observed ones. In my simulation 6.06% of samples were more extreme than steps A but only 1.16% of samples were more extreme than steps B.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The increments in a random walk are *exchangeable*, so it would be reasonable to use a permutation test to test the underlying hypothesis of exchangeability here.  The blue "walk" will certainly fail that test, which will alert you to the fact that it is not a random walk.